# How to append html using jquery in an indented manner?

Tags: jquery, html, append, indentation

I have

```
$('body').append("<div id=block> <center> <input type=submit value=submit id=sub> </center> <p id=display_message> </p> </div>");
```

Instead of this I want to write the code inside append() in an indented manner like this

```
$('body').append("<div id=block> 
                     <center> <input type=submit value=submit id=sub> </center> 
                     <p id=display_message> </p>
                  </div>");
```

but it shows illegal token error.
Please help

Comment: have to escape  line breaks in javascript strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you  need to put `\` after end of each line

```
$('body').append("<div id=block>\
                 <center> <input type=submit value=submit id=sub> </center>\
                 <p id=display_message> </p>\
              </div>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fk2w0cq3/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var content = "<div id=block>"+
                     "<center> <input type='submit' value='submit' id='sub'> </center> "+
                     "<p id='display_message'> </p>"+
                  "</div>"
$('body').append(content);
```